# psexec executes remote bat at local command line but not in python shell

Tags: python, windows

psexec is installed in system32 directory and at the windows CMD line or powershell is able to execute a remote bat file on another server (which in turns executes an SSIS package and the data is verified as loaded).

I'm attempting to build this into a python script executed locally, but when I run the following line in a python shell a CMD window is opened and what *looks like* the classic 'psexec is not a recognized internal or external command' error appears (but the CMD window closes so quickly that I'm not 100%).

Following is executed unsuccessfully in python:
import os
os.system(r"psexec.exe \servername\ d:\gis\gis_data\gps\gps_data_sql\importgpsdata.bat")

Following is executed successfully in windows CM line:
psexec.exe \servername\ d:\gis\gis_data\gps\gps_data_sql\importgpsdata.bat

d:\etc. being the location of the remote bat to be executed.

For a simple bat execution, I don't think subproccess is required. I have also tried to provide the explicit location of psexec.exe with no luck either.

I'm just at a loss as to why psexec will execute just fine at the command line but not in the python shell.

Comment: It's true that using subprocess won't change anything here, but I'd still suggest that you do. It's just so much better.

Comment: I've been trying to keep it simple for hammering out the workflow, and will likely adopt subproccess as some point. I'm not sure I can pass python variables down into command line execution which will eventually be critical to my final workflow. My GIS server receives a text upload of GPS data and passes that to a known location, overwriting an exiting file. The bat runs dtexec against an SSIS package using the text file as an input. Fine and dandy until multiple processes running at once. 50 users tops, but it will happen. So, if was able to pass unique text file names all the way through...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that this is due to the [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx). For a 32 bit process on a 64 bit system, that will redirect references to `system32` to `SysWOW64`.

You have a 64 bit system, and are running 32 bit Python. When you invoke `psexec` from `cmd.exe` it finds `psexec` because `cmd.exe` is a 64 bit process, and so not subject to redirection. Likewise for PowerShell. But your 32 bit Python cannot see into the 64 bit system directory. So it cannot find `psexec`.

You also tried to execute `C:\Windows\system32\psexec` and that failed in the same way. For exactly the same reason. The redirector means that to a 32 bit process that path actually refers to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psexec`.

Test out this hypothesis by invoking `C:\Windows\Sysnative\Psexe.exe`. That should work from your 32 bit Python because it uses the `Sysnative` alias that allows 32 bit processes to see into the 64 bit system directory.

Any long term solution should involve putting `psexec` somewhere else. Remember that the system directory belongs to the system and you should not be modifying its contents. I suggest that you create a dedicated folder for such utilities, and add that directory to your `PATH`.

Comment: David Heffernan currently rules my world. I would have never been able to sniff this out. Now all I gotta to is roll this up into my arcgis geoprocessing service and I've got a live GPS upload kit.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is one of those things that is immediately obvious once you've seen it a couple of times, and impossible to fathom out if you never have!